# Calculate the height of window at a time of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was created a code for calculating the height at a time of scrolling.

1. When the window height is greater than my first div section height,
   the second section will show.
2. When i get back to top from bottom the second section will hide.

Code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var $height = $(window).scrollTop();

    var outerheigth = $(".smart-light-top-bnr").height();

    var sliderheigth = $(".smart-light-edu1").height();

    var outheigth = parseInt(outerheigth)+parseInt(sliderheigth);

      if($height >= outerheigth && $height <= outheigth) {
        document.getElementById("smart-light-edu").style.display = "block"; 

    } else {
        document.getElementById("smart-light-edu").style.display = "none"; 

    }});
```

Issue : When i get back to top of window the div is not hide.

Thanks

Comment: can you just check with `if($height <= outheigth) {` instead of `if($height >= outerheigth && $height <= outheigth) {`

Comment: and if you are using jQuery then why don't you are using `$("#smart-light-edu").hide()`

Comment: Thanks Dhaval Purohit,  User cross from first section then second div show, and reached on third div, again second section need to hide

Comment: then you need all the section height first

Comment: And based on that you need to make conditions that if main height rest in the between those section the section should show otherwise not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh!. Finally i get the solution, after searching and facing some bug..
Here is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var $height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var outerheigth = $(".smart-light-top-bnr").height();
    var sliderheigth = $(".smart-light-edu1").height();
    var outheigth = parseInt(outerheigth)+parseInt(sliderheigth);

    if($height >= outerheigth && $height <= outheigth) {
        swiper.init();
    }

});
```

Happy coding !!!